# SQL - Trazer o nome da cidade com o maior número de vendas

Tags: sql

Qual seria a query MySql para trazer o nome da cidade com o maior número de vendas?

```
CREATE TABLE `clientes` (
    `Codigo` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Nome` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Cidade` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `vendas` (
    `Codigo_Venda` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CodigoCliente` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ValorVenda` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Tentei essa query, mas ela pode trazer valores errados:

```
SELECT C.Cidade, MAX(V.ValorVenda)
FROM Clientes C INNER JOIN vendas V ON C.Codigo = V.Codigo_Venda
GROUP BY C.cidade
```

Tentei juntar `max(sum(campo))` mas o mysql nao está aceitando

Comment: MAX retorna o maior valor de um campo. O MySQL não deixou MAX(SUM()) porque ele não consegue resolver agregações aninhadas. Vamos pensar um pouco no seu exercício. Abstraindo o banco de dados, como você descobria qual cidade teve MAIS VENDAS? (quantidade de vendas != maior valor somado das vendas)

Comment: Outro ponto: o seu JOIN está comparando código do cliente com código de venda, deveria ser `CodigoCliente`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso você queira trazer o nome da cidade na qual obteve mais vendas, baseado na soma dos valores totais, independente da quantidade de vendas, você pode utilizar a função [SUM](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_sum.asp):

```
SELECT C.Cidade, SUM(V.ValorVenda)
FROM Clientes C INNER JOIN vendas V ON C.Codigo = V.Codigo_Venda
GROUP BY C.cidade
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Caso você queira trazer o nome da cidade que mais obteve vendas em quantidade, e não a soma dos valores, você pode utilizar a função [COUNT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_count.asp):

```
SELECT C.Cidade, COUNT(*)
FROM Clientes C INNER JOIN vendas V ON C.Codigo = V.Codigo_Venda
GROUP BY C.cidade
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Mas no caso eu apenas quero trazer o nome da cidade com mais vendas, não pode vir a coluna de count ou qualquer outra coluna, apenas o nome da cidade.
Quando eu retiro essas colunas no início do select a minha query dá errado e não estou conseguindo colocar isso na parte de baixo de forma que funcione.

Muito grato!

Comment: Bom, não vejo motivos que impacte trazer ou não a coluna do count, mas não vai ser possível excluí-la e obter a query que deseja. O que você pode fazer é colocar a query em parenteses e selecionar o nome da cidade sem o count, mas ainda sim fazendo a sua query. Exemplo:

Comment: Vai ficar desformatado por causa que está em comentário, mas tente isso: "SELECT Cidade
FROM (SELECT C.Cidade, COUNT(*)
FROM Clientes C INNER JOIN vendas V ON C.Codigo = V.Codigo_Venda
GROUP BY C.cidade
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1) AS Cidade;"

Comment: Agora eu entendi o esquema de trazer apenas o nome da cidade utilizando um select por fora. Muito grato a todos! 

Comment: Caso tenha resolvido seu problema, por favor marque a resposta como aceita para que a pergunta não fique como aberta. Abraço.

Answer (score 1):

fazendo sum no valor de vendas vai trazer a que mais vendeu em valor, trazer a que tem mais vendas seria com o count

```
SELECT C.Cidade, count(1) 
    FROM Clientes
 C INNER JOIN vendas V ON C.Codigo = V.Codigo_Venda
 GROUP BY C.cidade
```